# Combining and duplicating elements in lists

Tags: python, list

I'm looking to sort of combine two lists and i'm not really sure where to begin.
I have a list:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d']
```

with 4 elements, and a list of 5 numbers:

```
n = [0,10,20,30,40]
```

What i want to do is create a new list of lists that links the range between the numbers to the letters. Something like this:

```
newlist = [['a',0,10],['b',10,20],['c',20,30],['d',30,40]]
```

Is there an efficient way of doing this with list comprehensions?

Comment: `[i for i in [['a',0,10],['b',10,20],['c',20,30],['d',30,40]]]`

Comment: write some relative code to avoid downvoting your question. Start with simple list comprehension or `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
newlist=[[item, n[j], n[j+1]] for j, item in enumerate(l)]
```

The output is exactly what you asked for:

```
[['a', 0, 10], ['b', 10, 20], ['c', 20, 30], ['d', 30, 40]]
```

This code deal with a list of any length, the only condition that is imposed - the list `l` must be one element less than the list `n` that, as far as I understood from the problem statement, holds

Answer (score 3):

Short *one-liner* using [***zip()***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
result = [list(i) for i in zip(l, n, n[1:])]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['a', 0, 10], ['b', 10, 20], ['c', 20, 30], ['d', 30, 40]]
```